# Add related Keyword Google Custom Search (CSE)

Tags: drupal, meta-tags, google-custom-search

I use Drupal 7 with MetaTags Module. But this is not a Drupal specific problem.

This Website use the CSE (Google Custom Search) to find content.
Now, i want to add to each content related keyword.

> When I create a content about italy, so the **related keyword** are e.g. "*pizza, pasta, fiat ..."*

Now I think the "< meta keyword />"  would be the solution. But this dont work.
If I add the keywords in the "< meta description />", after reindexing i find the "italy" content when i search "pizza". But the "< meta-tag description />" is reserved for google result

Is there not a simple solution with "" tag?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

I add synonyms for Search Results
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2631030?hl=en